# Как использовать переменные из другого файла в php?

Tags: php

есть файл с данными для подключения к базе, лежит в отдельном файле. Как данные из него передать в другой файл?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться конструкцией *namespace*'ов (php 7+)

**Пример**:

*Первый вариант*:

Пусть будет файл *ex1.php*:

```
<?php 
namespace example;
class Ex{
    public static $variable = 'Jack Sparrow';
}
```

И файл *ex2.php*, в котором нужно воспользоваться переменной из класса *Ex* **$variable**:

```
<?php
include 'ex1.php'; //или любой другой оператор подключения файлов php (include_once, require, require_once)
use example as ex;
echo ex\Ex::$variable; //выведет Jack Sparrow

/* или 
use example\Ex;
echo Ex::$variable;
*/
```

Да, подключать файл нужно все равно (оператор **include**).

Такой подход более предпочтительный с точки зрения ООП и более удобный, в случае больших проектов.

В проектах с *MVC*-структурой, например, как [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150267/), подключать такие файлы в моделях не нужно будет (они автоматически подключаются в классе *Route*. И да, та статья написана в 2012, без использования *namespace*'ов, но при желании, можно легко их добавить, особенно будет удобно, если Ваш проект разрастется).

*Второй вариант*:

Пусть будет файл *ex1.php*:

```
<?php 
$variable = 'Test';

function doSomething($z){
   echo $z;
}
```

И файл *ex2.php*:

```
<?php
require 'ex1.php';
echo $variable; //Получим Test
doSomething('Привет, русскоязычный Stackoverflow!'); //выведет надпись в кавычках
```

Переменная и метод из файла *ex1.php*, но, подключив его, мы получаем к ним доступ.

Важно отметить, что подключать файлы нужно **до** их использования в стороннем файле.

Приведенный второй пример подойдет для небольших проектов, или какого-нибудь небольшого скрипта.

Comment: А если мне нужно передать данные из другого файла в класс?

Comment: call_user_func_array http://php.net/call_user_func_array

Comment: А вообще, для работы с классами советую использовать http://php.net/Autoload

Answer (score 3):

Подключить файл через

```
include 'file.php';
// или
require 'file.php';
```

И после подключения, можно использовать.

Comment: Делать это естественно желательно в самом начале :).

Comment: Не факт, есть моменты когда не нужно грузить лишний код.